# how to solve Plugin capacitor that is depricated?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

Good day all
May I inquire as to why this plugin has been depricated? and how should I resolve it?
below are my capacitor and ionic info.

**Capacitor:
Capacitor CLI      : 4.0.1
@capacitor/android : 4.0.1
@capacitor/core    : 4.0.1
Ionic:
Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.1
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.2.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.1.0
@angular/cli                  : 14.1.0
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0**

[image]

Comment: Plugins is deprecated, Previously it was something like const { Camera, et...} = Plugins; And u used to put Camera.capture...; now no need to use plugins at all.. just import the plugin ex.: import { Camera } from "..." and in ur code u use Camera.capture... as before.. just the way of implementation of Plugins changed...

Answer (score 0):

In Capacitor 2 all core plugins were bundled with Capacitor itself, but in Capacitor 3 all plugins were removed and distributed in their own packages.

So, to use Device plugin you have to install `@capacitor/device` npm package and use it like `import { Device } from ‘@capacitor/device’;` instead of getting Device from Plugins object.